# Joint density function with absolute value

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let X and Y have joint density
fXY (x, y) = 
kxy^2 where j0 ≤ x, y ≤ 1, 
0 otherwise.

Compute Pr(|X − Y | < 0.5).

So I found that k=6, but can't figure out the probability part after working on it for a while (the book doesn't provide any examples with absolute values).

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** Draw the $1\times 1$ square on which the joint density function "lives."

Draw the lines $x-y=0.5$ and $x-y=-0.5$. We want the probability that the pair $(X,Y)$ lands in the part $A$ of the square that lies between these two lines.

To do that, we want to integrate the joint density over the region $A$.

For me is easier to find first the integrals of the joint density over the two "leftover" triangles, the one on the north-west and the one on the south-east. However, in this case we can alternately work with $A$ directly, being careful to treat the intervals $0\le x\le \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}\le x\le 1$ separately.